# What is the difference between a Listener and a CaptureListener in LibGDX Scene2D

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

According to the [documentaton](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html).

Adding a listener : `Add a listener to receive events that hit this actor.`

Adding a capture listener : `Adds a listener that is only notified during the capture phase.`

I was not successfully able to find information on this so called `capture phase`. What is the difference between both listeners? When should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the official LibGDX [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#event-system), capture listeners are called before "normal" listeners to give you a chance to intercept the events. (i.e. Active window cancels click on button under it)

> First, during the "capture" phase an event is given to each actor from
> the root down to the target actor. Only capture listeners are notified
> during this phase. This gives parents a chance to intercept and
> potentially cancel events before children see them. Next, during the
> "normal" phase the event is given to each actor from the target up to
> the root. Only normal listeners are notified during this phase. This
> allows actors to handle an event themselves or let the parent have a
> try at it.

To intercept an event, you must can either use `event.cancel()`, which will prevent propagation but also mark the event as cancelled or use `event.stop()` which will also prevent propagation but without cancelling the event.

When an event is cancelled the code that fired the actor will know and may respond accordingly. For example, if the click on a `Button` is cancelled, it will avoid changing its `isChecked` state. The details of what happen when an event is cancelled depends entirely on the actor or code firing the event.